# Firebase multiple file upload: How to ensure the URLs are downloaded in exact order they were uploaded?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, promise, firebase-storage

here is what I am trying to do with my web app on Firebase:

1. Let the user define the order of uploads when uploading multiple files
2. Upload the files in the defined order
3. Download and store the URLs in the defined order to be passed on to another function

Below is the code that does #2 and #3. The issue is, while the files are actually uploaded in the intended order, the URLs are not stored in the intended order. I guess the reason is that getDownLoadURL() is an async operation, so the URLs for the bigger files are downloaded slower and thus stored later than intended. For example, something like below happens:

```
 upload order: [1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg];
 intended url array: [url_to_1.jpg, url_to_2.jpg, url_to_3.jpg];
 actual url array: [url_to_1.jpg,url_to_3.jpg,url_to_2.jpg];
```

I tested this multiple times, and the issue persists.

Here is what I am trying to do: ensure that upload of the next file starts only after the URL is downloaded and stored. i.e. not asynchronously but synchronously.  Below is the code I am using currently. What would be the fix to do this?

```
const url_array_get = () => {
    const user=firebase.auth().currentUser;
    let photos1=null;
    //Code to sort the photos in the intended order
    if (photoorder!==null) {
        photos1 = photoorder.map(position => photos[position - 1]);
    }
    else {
        photos1 = photos;
    }
    //Code to upload the files in the intended order, store the urls, and return them for the next function
    const promises=[];
    photos1.forEach((photo)=> {
        const a=photo.name;
        const a1=a.split('.');
        const b=uuidv4()+'.'+a1[1]; 
        let storageRef=firebase.storage().ref('data/'+user.uid+'/posts/'+b);
          promises.push(
              storageRef.put(photo).then((snapshot)=>{
                  return snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL()
              })
          )
     })
    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You can maintain a unique (let's say the date and time) key when uploading your files and when downloading them just sort them based on that key. Will that help you achieve your purpose?